# Html Partial MVC passing a Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass this Model in the Partial Method

```
@Html.Partial("_RefillModal",new Refill()
                                     {
                                         PatientId=Model.Id
                                     })
```

Now in the _RefillModal, I am trying to Read the PatientId by doing Model.PatientId. However, I am not getting a Value.

I can get the Value of the ID by doing this

```
@Html.Partial("_RefillModal",new Refill(),new ViewDataDictionary(){{"PatientId",Model.Id}})
```

Here is what I am trying to do in the Partial View

```
@Html.Hidden("Refill.PatientId",Model.PatientId)
```

Here is the Html Markup that happens

```
<input id="PatientId" name="PatientId" type="hidden" value="">
```

However when I do @Modal.PatientId anywhere on the page I do get the Value

So it looks like, if I put anything inside the Form it gets Overriden. Is there a work around?

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
//any custom input here gets overriden

}
```

Comment: Can you post your Partial View markup?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see where the issue is since you didn't post your `Partial View` but I'll offer a few suggestions. Make sure that you've declared the actual `Model` to be of type `Refill` in your `_RefillModal`.

```
@model Refill
```

The next step is to make sure that you're actually passing in a value in this line of code:

```
@Html.Partial("_RefillModal", new Refill()
                                 {
                                     /** Make sure that Model.Id actually 
                                         contains some value. */
                                     PatientId = Model.Id
                                 })
```